# How can I automate a detection of midi data inside of the computer in codes?

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi I would like to make a chrome web app with google script that would launch automatically when MIDI data is detected and would record it into .midi files. The files are then saved into google drive. Whenever there is no detected midi data for 2 minutes the program would save the recorded .midi data into their google drive account.

My goal with this chrome app is for musicians that are hit by inspiration to have it always saved for if they forgot their piece of art. because all they would have to do is to plug their electronic instrument into their computer and launch the app once and for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible with apps script.
 Need to write a native app (ie win64 exe).
Once written and can save midi to disk u can then make it so the midi goes to google drive.